# Cannot migrate new table in asp.net because there is an existing table in code first migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC website. For interacting with database, I am using Entity Framework with code first approach. But now I am having a problem in adding/migrating new table and entity to my model and database.

First I created a entity class

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(60)]
        public String MmName { get; set; }
    }
```

But for this entity, I created database manually. I did not use any migration command. Then I run the app and register a user using built-in identity registration system. So database tables are created successfully. Then I continued development. I was working fine. After I developed everything dealing with Category, I tried to add another entity and database table.

So I created a entity class like this

```
public class Region
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(70)]
        public String MmName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public String GeoLocation { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public String Description { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public String MmDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I run the following command to update database

```
enable-migrations
add-migration "CreateRegion"
update-database
```

I got this error

Here is already an object named 'Category' in the database.

This is my initiaizer class

```
public class ContextInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AyarDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AyarDbContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

How can I update database using command line? I want to migrate from command line because I am practising code first approach.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options at this point:

1) Drop the table from the database and re run the migration. It will create both tables for you.

2) Modify the migration file so it's not trying to create the Category table. This goes against how Code First is supposed to work but you're already in that situation by having existing tables.